# how can i detect 1-time e-credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, bin

I need to detect credit cards that are 1-time credit cards (they become obsolete after the first payment).

I know there are some bin ranges database out there. Can you share your experience on this point ?

Thank you for your help

Jerome Wagner

Comment: Does your payment service not do this for you? If not, I would probably get one that does.

Comment: no it doesn't ; i am looking for a generic way to do it, independent of the payment service provider. In any case, i would take any advice on a psp that does offer this feature. thxs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is usually provided by the processor that is closest to the interchange.  So if you're using a middleware like Payflow Pro with Chase-Paymentech as a processor, you can ask Chase-Paymentech for it.  I'd be surprised if they actually have this information though.  In the past, the lists I've seen only classify the cards as fleet, commercial, or corporate for purposes of determining the Level 2 and 3 data that needs to be sent.  All the consumer type cards appear to be grouped together as a single category.

If you are running through multiple layers of middleware (like Authorize.Net -> Cybersource -> some bank), start asking up the chain.  If the middleware solution provides processing based on the card type, they may have the data you need (if it exists).

The BIIN ranges change sometimes too....so whatever solution you make, make it so you can update the data periodically.  I've lived through instances where the design of the lookup wasn't really intended to EVER change, and then had to deal with major production "severity-1" fixes because employees of their biggest client were using P-Cards in a new range and causing settlements to fail when the software didn't find the new range classified as P-Cards.  Of course, no one knew the ranges had been updated so it took a few weeks for someone to finally get the idea of comparing the failed cards to known BIIN ranges.  It might have seemed obvious, but it is a little difficult when the card number is encrypted and you can't actually see the BIIN easily.

Hope it helps even if it isn't a direct answer.  Getting to someone that knew where to obtain the list usually took some time since most everyone that answers the phones at these places has very little knowledge about the complete process or even where to look to find the BIIN range list.  When we did get it, it was in the form of a screen-dump report from a green screen app placed in a plain text file.